# Как настроить шаблон html или форму регистрации под шаблон? Django

Tags: html, django

Есть готовый шаблон регистрации взятый с интернета и не хотелось бы его сильно менять.. Как мне настроить шаблон или форму так, чтобы сильно не поменять шаблон и все выглядело нормально?
Вот форма:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Введите имя пользователя'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

А вот стандартный div:

```
<div class="col-2-mt-2">
   <div class="input-group">
      <label class="label">Логин</label>
        <input class="input--style-4" type="text" name="first_name">
   </div>
</div>
```

Например куда мне вставить {{form.username}}? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Куда нравиться туда и ставьте. Не понимаю смысла вашей проблемы. Берете и не меняете шаблон. Чего трудного-то? В label подставляете label ваших полей, если он вам нужен. В input сами поля...

Comment: Ну типо я вставил и появилось доп.поле.

Comment: Ну значит вы что-то неправильно вставили.

Comment: Ну я уже сделал немного по-своему, но спасибо